# Why is the implementation of cross entropy different in Pytorch and Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, precision

I am going through the documentation of Cross Entropy in Pytorch and Tensorflow. I understand that they are modifying the naive implementation of Cross Entropy to solve for the potential numeric over/underflows. However, I am unable to understand as to how these modifications are helping at all.

The [implementation of Cross Entropy in Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) follows the following logic -

[image]

where [image] is the softmax score and [image] is the raw score.

This doesn't seem to solve the problem because [image] also leads to numeric overflow.

Now, we contrast it with Tensorflow's implementation (I got it [from a discussion in Github](http://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/427#issuecomment-491514691). This might be completely wrong) -

Let [image] is the vector of all k raw logit scores.
[image] 
While this solves the problem of overflow but it runs into problems of underflow because it is possible that [image] which would lead to an even smaller [image]

Can someone please help me in understanding what's going on here?

Comment: This is not how it is implemented in PyTorch. They also [subtract the max](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1830e4f08cd3b41df9d643211762156b67371611/aten/src/ATen/native/SoftMax.cpp#L44), otherwise it would be numerically unstable. Point to both their implementation and let us know if there is any difference. I don't think there will be, apart from _cosmetics_.

Comment: Oh, is it? Well that handles the numeric overflow part but what about the numeric underflow? The source of my information is https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Comment: Most people don't care about the underflow. Looking at the naive raw formula, the very small values don't really change anything when there is at least one dominating large value.

Answer (score 1):

Answering here by combining answers from the comment section for the benefit of the community.

Since you have addressed the issue of *numeric overflow* in **PyTorch**, that is handled by subtracting the max value like below([from here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1830e4f08cd3b41df9d643211762156b67371611/aten/src/ATen/native/SoftMax.cpp#L44)).

```
scalar_t z = std::exp(input_data[d * dim_stride] - max_input);
```

Coming to TensorFlow's implementation of Cross entropy the issue of *underflow* is not that major since it is numerically ignored with the dominating large value.

Answer (score 1):

In PyTorch

```
loss = F.cross_entropy(x, target)
```

is equivalent to:

```
lp = F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)
loss = F.nll_loss(lp, target)
```

For the `log_softmax` we do not calculate log of softmax directly instead use [log-sum-exp](https://dejanbatanjac.github.io/2019/07/04/softmax-vs-sigmoid.html) trick:

```
def log_softmax(x): 
    return x - x.exp().sum(-1).log().unsqueeze(-1)
```

Which is numerically sable. Both PyTorch and Tensorflow use this trick.